# Move voice channel discord js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been coding with Python for Discord but I wanted to make the switch to JS as there is more. I am having some trouble, the bot did not have a join or leave command. So I created one. I can get the join working but the bot cant leave.

```
const util = require("../util");

var arr = []
module.exports = {
    name: "join",
    aliases: ["j"],
    exec: async (msg, args) => {
        const { music } = msg.guild;
        if (!msg.member.voice.channel)
            return msg.channel.send(`:x: You need to be in a voice channel to run this command!`);
        if (msg.guild.me.voice.channel && !msg.guild.me.voice.channel.equals(msg.member.voice.channel))
            return msg.channel.send(`:thumbsup: **I've left** ${msg.guild.me.voice.channel} **and joining** ${msg.member.voice.channel}!`);
            await music.join(msg.member.voice.channel);
        const missingPerms = util.missingPerms(msg.guild.me.permissionsIn(msg.member.voice.channel), ["CONNECT", "SPEAK"]);
        if ((!music.player || !music.player.playing) && missingPerms.length)
            return msg.channel.send(`Hmm :thinking: I am unable to join you're voice chat! I am missing the permission: ${missingPerms.map(x => `\`${x}\``).join(", ")}. Do I have access to this voice chat?`);
        else {
            await music.join(msg.member.voice.channel);
        }


    }
}
```

How would I get the bot to move and leave?

Comment: Which part of this is not working as intended? Any errors?

Comment: Hey @MrMythical thanks for the reply. In python I could do voice.disconnect() but I cant figure out how to disconnect from voice in JS. In line 10 I either want the bot to disconnect and rejoin the new channel or like music.move_to() something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Discord.js v12

Hmm I see your problem is really simple and you could've find it in the [**`Official Documentation`**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/general/welcome).

Instead of trying to `switch` channels you can just quit the current one and join a new one using [`<ThisChannel>.leave()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=leave) and then [`<NewChannel>.join()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join)

PS : Your code is kinda messy so if you want it to be more readable you can use [`msg.member.voice.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel) for the member's channel and [`msg.guild.me.voice.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel) for the channel you're in, and it will be `null` if the target isn't there, to join the member's voice channel it's [`msg.member.voice.channel.join()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join) without putting anything in the ()

To be more precise, your new code would look something like

```js
        const { music } = msg.guild;
        if (!msg.member.voice.channel)
            return msg.channel.send(`:x: You need to be in a voice channel to run this command!`);
        if (msg.guild.me.voice.channel && !msg.guild.me.voice.channel.equals(msg.member.voice.channel))
            return msg.channel.send(`:thumbsup: **I've left** ${msg.guild.me.voice.channel} **and joining** ${msg.member.voice.channel}!`);
            await msg.guild.me.voice.channel.leave()
            await msg.member.voice.channel.join()
        const missingPerms = util.missingPerms(msg.guild.me.permissionsIn(msg.member.voice.channel), ["CONNECT", "SPEAK"]);
        if ((!music.player || !music.player.playing) && missingPerms.length)
            return msg.channel.send(`Hmm :thinking: I am unable to join you're voice chat! I am missing the permission: ${missingPerms.map(x => `\`${x}\``).join(", ")}. Do I have access to this voice chat?`);
        else await music.join(msg.member.voice.channel);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ill give it a shot! Thanks